# javascript object always null

Tags: javascript, object

Here is my code:

```
myExt = {};
myExt.Panel = function (config){
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    /*Do something (a lot) with config and d here
    // a lot of code here
    */
    return
    {
        div:d,
        events:e,
        customattribs:ca
     };
}
```

Here is my caller:

```
var p = new myExt.Panel({
    id:'parent',
    events:{
        onload:function(){
            alert("onload");
        }
    },
    //more configs
});
```

if I do

```
console.log(p)
```

I get null. Please help me debug the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Automatic semicolon insertion](http://es5.github.com/x7.html#x7.9) has turned the return value of your function from:

```
return { div: d, events: 3, customattribs:ca };
```

into:

```
return;
```

It would be better if you stored the value you want to return in a variable, and then return that object:

```
var ret;
ret = {
    div: d,
    events: e,
    customattribs: ca
};
return ret;
```

Comment: @hrishikeshp19, I highly recommend reading everything Douglas Crockford has ever written about JavaScript, and watching [his talks](http://yuiblog.com/crockford/).

Comment: Or better, and less opinionated, run code through http://jsHint.com . It will catch this error for you.

Comment: Yep, this is one reason why I put parens around my `return` statements even though I often get scoffed at.

Comment: @jfriend00: You can't put parens around a `return` statement. It's a statement. If you mean around the expression whose result is returned, that wouldn't prevent this error.

Comment: @amnotiam - I nearly always use `return (expression);` and don't ever have this problem.

Comment: @jfriend00: That's because you're in the habit of never having a line break after the `return` statement. I don't wrap in parens, and I don't ever have this problem either, because I have the same habit.